# probleim with sending and receiving file from socket c++

Tags: c++, sockets, mfc

im trying to send a file from server to a client
Ive got this function in my server:

```
UINT CServerDlg::sendFile(WPARAM pParam)
{
    if (!AfxWinInit(::GetModuleHandle(NULL), NULL, ::GetCommandLine(), 0))
    {
        return FALSE;
    }
    else {
        if (AfxSocketInit() == FALSE)
        {
            return FALSE;
        }

        CSocket ServerSocket;
        if (ServerSocket.Create(Dport, SOCK_STREAM, NULL) == 0)
        {
            return FALSE;
        }
        else
        {
            if (ServerSocket.Listen(32) == FALSE)
            {
                ServerSocket.Close();
                return FALSE;
            }

        }


        CSocket Connector;
        if (ServerSocket.Accept(Connector))
        {
            char* buffer = NULL;

            FILE* fi = fopen(file_name.c_str(), "rb");
            if (!fi)
                return 0;

            //get the file length
            fseek(fi, 0, SEEK_END);
            long file_size = ftell(fi);
            fseek(fi, 0, SEEK_SET);

            //send packet's length first and then send the packet
            //(one file includes multiple packets) and SIZE_BUFFER=4096
            int result=-1;
            int size = (file_size < SIZE_BUFFER) ? (int)file_size : SIZE_BUFFER;
            while (file_size >= (long long)SIZE_BUFFER) {
                fread(buffer, size, 1, fi);
                result = send(Connector, (char*)&file_size, sizeof(int), 0);

                if (result == SOCKET_ERROR) return 0;
                do { size = send(Connector,buffer, size, 0); } while (size == -1);

                memset(buffer, 0, SIZE_BUFFER);
                file_size = file_size - (long long)size;
            }
            if (file_size != 0) {
                if (send(Connector, (char*)&file_size, sizeof(int), 0) == SOCKET_ERROR) return 0;
                fread(buffer, file_size, 1, fi);
                do { size = send(Connector,buffer, file_size, 0); } while (size == -1);

            }

            delete[] buffer;
            fclose(fi);
        }
        else {
            return 0;
        }
        Connector.Close();
        ServerSocket.Close();
    }
    return 1;
}
```

And on client file ive got this:

```
bool MainDlg::DownloadFile(char* file_name, int port) {
    if (!AfxWinInit(::GetModuleHandle(NULL), NULL, ::GetCommandLine(), 0))
    {
        // TODO: change error code to suit your needs
        return FALSE;
    }
    //copy tu demo
    if (AfxSocketInit() == FALSE)
    {
        return FALSE;
    }

    CSocket ClientSocket;
    ClientSocket.Create();

    if (ClientSocket.Connect(_T("127.0.0.1"), port) != 0)
    {
        char* buffer = NULL;
        int size = 0;
        FILE* fo = fopen(file_name, "wb");
        recv(ClientSocket, (char*)&size, sizeof(int), 0);
        while (size >= SIZE_BUFFER) {
            do { size = recv(ClientSocket, (char*)buffer, SIZE_BUFFER, 0); } while (size == -1);

            fwrite((char*)buffer, size, 1, fo);
            memset(buffer, 0, SIZE_BUFFER);
            size = recv(ClientSocket, (char*)&size, sizeof(int), 0);
        }
        if ((size != SOCKET_ERROR)) size = recv(ClientSocket, (char*)buffer, size, 0);
        else return 0;
        delete[] buffer;
        fclose(fo);
    }
    else {
        return 0;
    }
    ClientSocket.Close();
    return 1;
}
```

Server and client connected but it seemed to fail to send the packet. Even it failed to send but the execution file didnt call an error but when i debug it does. I get an unknown error at `fread(buffer, file_size, 1, fi)`:
Unhandled exception at 0x00007FF6F17BDF28 in Server.exe: An invalid parameter was passed to a function that considers invalid parameters fatal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must to allocate memory for buffer, because first parameter of `fread`:

> Pointer to a block of memory with a size of at least (`size*count`) bytes, converted to a `void*`.

Use [`malloc`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/c/malloc) or [`new`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new).

I would recommend using [`std::array`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) to not worry about deleting memory.

Comment: yeah, i try it and it fix the problem but the send function has return the wrong number.
I got the file has 7 byte and it returned 4

Comment: Because you wrote `send(Connector, (char*)&file_size, sizeof(int), 0);` the third parameter is length of data you want to send. You have to pass array length. For example `send(Connector, (char*)&file_size, buffer.length, 0);`. But remember if buffer is `char*` then `sizeof(buffer)` return size of pointer (4 or 8 bytes). If you use `std::array` just pass `buffer.size()`. Sorry for my bad english.